# Is it possible for my app to request permission to use resources from a third party app, not the basic android apps

Tags: android

I need an app that reads the messages from fb messenger and reacts to certain key words. Before i start i need to know if its even possible to get permission to read(not save) messages from fb. Of course users will approve this when installing.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with intents? https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/usage-notes

Comment: Thank you, ill read through this tonight

Answer (score 0):

Its up to those third party apps.  For it to be possible, they need to encourage this use and write a ContentProvider that provides that information, and publish the url of the content provider for you to query (along with the parameters of a query).  Otherwise there's no way to get at that information.  Very few to no messaging/social apps will do this due to privacy concerns.

Comment: I might have phrased the question wrong, I don't need the app to read through all the messages just the messages of the user that would be installing the app and providing permission to have his messages read. I do realize its still probably not possible because those messages would not be just my clients messages but also the other parties that he is chatting with ... Im basically just grasping for straws here

Comment: @KarlMarx Doesn't change the answer.  To gain access to the private data of an app, the app has to provide it to you via a content provider (or to via an SDK that either wraps the content provider/hits a web API).  If the other app doesn't decide to provide access, you can't get it.

Comment: Yeah i figured, just had to make sure.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jgv.chatmessagereader

Just found this app ... wouldn't it need to access the messages to read them aloud ?

Comment: @KarlMarx No, it would be using the accessibility APIs to read whatever is on the screen.  IT does not get a notification of incoming messages.  Also, access to accessibility APIs are limited by Google Play policies.  Your use would not be allowed.

Comment: It could also be working just for SMS messages, which does have an API to read them as part of Android (although Google is also cracking down and limiting access for privacy reasons).

Comment: I checked it is not just for SMS ... but if I understand you correctly, i can avoid asking for permission from facebook and there is a way to make the app read what is on the screen(leaving aside the Google Play policies issue).

Comment: You might also be able to find some functionality in the FB SDK to read messages.  But implementing that (if it exists) would require you to write separate code for each messaging service you're trying to integrate with (FB, Hnagouts, WeChat, Snapchat, WhatsApp, etc)